# QGIS, Number of Lines through a Point (of over lapping multiline shapefile)

Tags: qgis-3, intersection, overlapping-features, count, network-analysis

I am doing an irrigation system analysis, for that there are multiple overlapping lines are passing through multiple points.

1. one number of line means a unit volume of the system,
2. and point means a gauging station.
3. and the number of lines passing means the flow throughput of the gauging station

**How can I find the number of lines passing through a point?**

Comment: Add some more information about what have you tried and what software and tools are you using?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing what you are trying to count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `point` layer and a `line` layer, then you can count the lines near by the points using field calculator:

1. Open the attribute table of point layer
2. Open the field calculator dialog (abacus icon)
3. Enter the following expression

```
    aggregate( layer:='line', aggregate:='count', expression:="ATTR",filter:=  intersects( buffer(geometry(@parent) , 1), $geometry) )
```

[image]

Substitute "ATTR" with any column name in your `line` layer. The buffer is necessary to find lines very close. Substitute 1 for buffer to any reasonable value in the CRS units.

Comment: Thank you very much  @Zoltan

Comment: Thank you very much @babel